# How get facebook like "New stories" Button iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want the similar function that facebook app use to load new post feeds in their app, It works like they check for feed update every few minutes and if their are new feed are available then there will be a button will appear on top of Table view named new feed and when it tapped it will load all new feed cell one by one with animation not not reloading complete table. I just want some guidance any help will be appreciated

[image]

Edit: 
What I have now is
A UITableView which loads feed from the server when first loads and there is also pull to refresh control their.

What I have to do now is.

1. Put a timer to check feed changes( easy to do no problem with that)
2. load new table view cell on top without making any changes on the
   screen except the new feed button.
3. On tap of button scroll up to show all new cell.

Comment: Do you have any of the above functionality already working and you just need to know how to add a button that hovers over the table view?

Comment: no i don't have any of the above functionality already working I want full functionality.

Comment: Do you have a `UITableView` set up? Are you already doing an API call to pull in your information? Do you then have a `NSTimer` running in the background to refresh the information? 

If you do not have any of the above, I would research each of those individually because you are asking how to do many separate steps but don't appear to have done any work yet.

Comment: yes I have UITableView which load it self first time but all other feature I have to implement I will update question for more detail.